# Django, retrieve image using url and save it ThumbnailerImageField of easy_thumbnails

Tags: django, easy-thumbnails

I have used `easy_thumbnails`to store images in my application. I have a model name `Profile` that has `picture` field which is ThumbnailerImageField. 
In my code I am fetching image using a url I have using the follwing code

```
f = urllib.request.urlretrieve(picture_url)
```

Now, f[0] is a string containing path to file in `/tmp/` directory.
I want to save this image to my picture field. So, I used following code

```
profile.picture.save(os.path.basename(picture), File(open(f[0])))
```

But the problem is that the saved file is corrupted for some reason and I am unable to open it. Whereas when I check for the file in`/tmp/`, it is a proper image file. Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

My field definition is as following
`picture = ThumbnailerImageField(upload_to=name, max_length=3072)`

and `name` is as following

```
def name(inst, fname):
f = sha256((fname + str(timezone.now())).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
f += fname
return '/'.join([inst.__class__.__name__, f])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from django.core.files.temp import NamedTemporaryFile
try:
    img_temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
    img_temp.write(
        urllib2.urlopen(picture_url).read()
    )
    img_temp.flush()
    profile.picture.save('picture.jpg', File(img_temp))
    profile.save()
except:
    pass
```